# MySQLdb Python connector building and installation command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 255

Tags: python, mysql-python

I'm running Mac Lion. I've installed python 2.7.2 and django 1.3.1. Both of them work fine. To make python work with mysql, I have to install MySQL-python-1.2.3 -- but I can't get the build to work. For the MySQL, I have XAMPP and I've set XAMPP's bin to the system environment path for the mysql_config the building needs.

```
SOFXGF-AIR:MySQL-python-1.2.3 Sofia$ python setup.py buildrunning build
running build_py
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Dversion_info=(1,2,3,'final',0) -D__version__=1.2.3 -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/mysql -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/_mysql.o -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -arch i386 -arch ppc -D_P1003_1B_VISIBLE -DSIGNAL_WITH_VIO_CLOSE -DSIGNALS_DONT_BREAK_READ -DIGNORE_SIGHUP_SIGQUIT -DDONT_DECLARE_CXA_PURE_VIRTUAL
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/unicodeobject.h:4,
from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:85,
from pymemcompat.h:10,
from _mysql.c:29:
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/stdarg.h:4:25: error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory
_mysql.c:36:23: error: my_config.h: No such file or directory
_mysql.c:38:19: error: mysql.h: No such file or directory
_mysql.c:39:26: error: mysqld_error.h: No such file or directory
_mysql.c:40:20: error: errmsg.h: No such file or directory
_mysql.c:76: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘MYSQL’
_mysql.c:90: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘MYSQL_RES’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_Exception’:
_mysql.c:120: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c:123: error: ‘CR_MAX_ERROR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:123: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
_mysql.c:123: error: for each function it appears in.)
_mysql.c:131: error: ‘CR_COMMANDS_OUT_OF_SYNC’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:132: error: ‘ER_DB_CREATE_EXISTS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:133: error: ‘ER_SYNTAX_ERROR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:134: error: ‘ER_PARSE_ERROR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:135: error: ‘ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:136: error: ‘ER_WRONG_DB_NAME’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:137: error: ‘ER_WRONG_TABLE_NAME’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:138: error: ‘ER_FIELD_SPECIFIED_TWICE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:139: error: ‘ER_INVALID_GROUP_FUNC_USE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:140: error: ‘ER_UNSUPPORTED_EXTENSION’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:141: error: ‘ER_TABLE_MUST_HAVE_COLUMNS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:170: error: ‘ER_DUP_ENTRY’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:213: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c:213: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘PyString_FromString’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ResultObject_Initialize’:
_mysql.c:363: error: ‘MYSQL_RES’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:363: error: ‘result’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:368: error: ‘MYSQL_FIELD’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:368: error: ‘fields’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:377: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘use’
_mysql.c:380: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c:382: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c:383: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
_mysql.c:386: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
_mysql.c:390: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘nfields’
_mysql.c:391: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
_mysql.c:438: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ResultObject_traverse’:
_mysql.c:450: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
_mysql.c:451: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ResultObject_clear’:
_mysql.c:462: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
_mysql.c:462: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
_mysql.c:462: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
_mysql.c:462: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
_mysql.c:463: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_Initialize’:
_mysql.c:475: error: ‘MYSQL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:475: error: ‘conn’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:500: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
_mysql.c:501: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
_mysql.c:537: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c:540: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c:540: error: ‘MYSQL_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:544: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c:544: error: ‘MYSQL_OPT_COMPRESS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:545: error: ‘CLIENT_COMPRESS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:548: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c:548: error: ‘MYSQL_OPT_NAMED_PIPE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:550: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c:550: error: ‘MYSQL_INIT_COMMAND’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:552: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c:552: error: ‘MYSQL_READ_DEFAULT_FILE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:554: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c:554: error: ‘MYSQL_READ_DEFAULT_GROUP’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:557: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c:557: error: ‘MYSQL_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:565: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c:583: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
_mysql.c:591: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_traverse’:
_mysql.c:672: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
_mysql.c:673: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_clear’:
_mysql.c:681: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
_mysql.c:681: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
_mysql.c:681: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
_mysql.c:681: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
_mysql.c:682: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_close’:
_mysql.c:697: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
_mysql.c:699: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c:701: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_affected_rows’:
_mysql.c:723: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
_mysql.c:724: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_dump_debug_info’:
_mysql.c:758: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
_mysql.c:760: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_autocommit’:
_mysql.c:784: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_commit’:
_mysql.c:807: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_rollback’:
_mysql.c:829: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_errno’:
_mysql.c:941: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
_mysql.c:942: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_error’:
_mysql.c:957: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
_mysql.c:958: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c:958: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘PyString_FromString’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_escape’:
_mysql.c:1089: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ResultObject_describe’:
_mysql.c:1169: error: ‘MYSQL_FIELD’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:1169: error: ‘fields’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:1172: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
_mysql.c:1173: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
_mysql.c:1174: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ResultObject_field_flags’:
_mysql.c:1205: error: ‘MYSQL_FIELD’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:1205: error: ‘fields’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:1208: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
_mysql.c:1209: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
_mysql.c:1210: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
_mysql.c: At top level:
_mysql.c:1251: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘MYSQL_ROW’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_row_to_tuple’:
_mysql.c:1257: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
_mysql.c:1259: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
_mysql.c:1259: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
_mysql.c:1262: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
_mysql.c:1263: error: ‘row’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c: At top level:
_mysql.c:1276: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘MYSQL_ROW’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_row_to_dict’:
_mysql.c:1281: error: ‘MYSQL_FIELD’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:1281: error: ‘fields’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:1283: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
_mysql.c:1285: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
_mysql.c:1285: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
_mysql.c:1286: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
_mysql.c:1289: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
_mysql.c:1290: error: ‘row’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c: At top level:
_mysql.c:1315: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘MYSQL_ROW’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_row_to_dict_old’:
_mysql.c:1320: error: ‘MYSQL_FIELD’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:1320: error: ‘fields’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:1322: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
_mysql.c:1324: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
_mysql.c:1324: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
_mysql.c:1325: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
_mysql.c:1328: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
_mysql.c:1329: error: ‘row’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c: At top level:
_mysql.c:1351: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘MYSQL_ROW’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql__fetch_row’:
_mysql.c:1362: error: ‘MYSQL_ROW’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:1362: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘row’
_mysql.c:1366: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘use’
_mysql.c:1367: error: ‘row’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:1367: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
_mysql.c:1370: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
_mysql.c:1373: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c:1381: error: too many arguments to function ‘convert_row’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ResultObject_fetch_row’:
_mysql.c:1405: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘MYSQL_ROW’
_mysql.c:1420: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
_mysql.c:1432: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘use’
_mysql.c:1446: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_character_set_name’:
_mysql.c:1513: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_get_client_info’:
_mysql.c:1604: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘PyString_FromString’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_get_host_info’:
_mysql.c:1618: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
_mysql.c:1619: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c:1619: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘PyString_FromString’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_get_proto_info’:
_mysql.c:1633: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
_mysql.c:1634: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_get_server_info’:
_mysql.c:1648: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
_mysql.c:1649: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c:1649: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘PyString_FromString’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_info’:
_mysql.c:1665: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
_mysql.c:1666: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c:1666: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_insert_id’:
_mysql.c:1698: error: ‘my_ulonglong’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:1698: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘r’
_mysql.c:1700: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
_mysql.c:1702: error: ‘r’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:1702: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_kill’:
_mysql.c:1719: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
_mysql.c:1721: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_field_count’:
_mysql.c:1740: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
_mysql.c:1742: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ResultObject_num_fields’:
_mysql.c:1757: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
_mysql.c:1758: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ResultObject_num_rows’:
_mysql.c:1773: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
_mysql.c:1774: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_ping’:
_mysql.c:1803: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
_mysql.c:1804: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c:1806: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_query’:
_mysql.c:1827: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
_mysql.c:1829: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_select_db’:
_mysql.c:1857: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
_mysql.c:1859: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_shutdown’:
_mysql.c:1878: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
_mysql.c:1880: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_stat’:
_mysql.c:1905: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
_mysql.c:1907: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c:1907: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_store_result’:
_mysql.c:1928: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
_mysql.c:1929: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
_mysql.c:1938: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_thread_id’:
_mysql.c:1967: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
_mysql.c:1969: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_use_result’:
_mysql.c:1989: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
_mysql.c:1990: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
_mysql.c:1999: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_dealloc’:
_mysql.c:2017: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_repr’:
_mysql.c:2029: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
_mysql.c:2031: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ResultObject_data_seek’:
_mysql.c:2048: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
_mysql.c:2049: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ResultObject_row_seek’:
_mysql.c:2062: error: ‘MYSQL_ROW_OFFSET’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:2062: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘r’
_mysql.c:2064: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
_mysql.c:2065: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘use’
_mysql.c:2070: error: ‘r’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:2070: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
_mysql.c:2071: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ResultObject_row_tell’:
_mysql.c:2083: error: ‘MYSQL_ROW_OFFSET’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:2083: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘r’
_mysql.c:2085: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
_mysql.c:2086: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘use’
_mysql.c:2091: error: ‘r’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:2091: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
_mysql.c:2092: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ResultObject_dealloc’:
_mysql.c:2100: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
_mysql.c: At top level:
_mysql.c:2331: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
_mysql.c:2338: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
_mysql.c:2345: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c:2352: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c:2359: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c:2422: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
_mysql.c:2422: error: initializer element is not constant
_mysql.c:2422: error: (near initialization for ‘_mysql_ResultObject_memberlist[0].offset’)
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_getattr’:
_mysql.c:2444: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
gcc-4.2: error trying to exec '/usr/bin/powerpc-apple-darwin11-gcc-4.2.1': execvp: No such file or directory
lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/folders/jr/zhr6zd952zv84lqwbhm05k4m0000gn/T//ccthbt7t.out
error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 255
```

I'm not sure if this is right but I also tried `sudo env ARCHFLAGS='-arch x86_64' python setup.py build` as I noticed that `-arch ppc` is being mentioned in the error message. However, I'm still getting the same errors. Also there might be something about `No such file or directory` errors? I have XCode 4 installed.

Comment: I have XAMPP's MySQL. I've added XAMPP's bin to the system path. Won't XAMPP's MySQL work?

Answer (score 5):

You need the mysql-devel package installed as well. Always watch for the .h extension files. If you see errors because of them it means the developer package isn't installed and what you ware compiling requires it.

Since you are on a Mac, you'll need the uncompiled source files for MySQL so that it can access those header files. You can grab it here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=405008

You will likely have to tell  the build command where those files are located. Try python ./setup.py --help

Comment: In case somebody bumps into this question needing help for ubuntu, the relevant packages are `python-dev` and `python3-dev` for python 2 and 3 respectively.

Answer (score 1):

For me:

```
yum install MySQL-python
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have mysql installed:

```
brew install mysql
```

If you have it (e.g. like MAMP), make sure that `mysql_config` is runnable (see: site.cfg).

Otherwise you can try to install mysql-python in other ways like:

using [ActivePython](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/mysql-python/):

```
easy_install mysql-connector-python
```

or using MySQL Python Connector:

```
pypm install mysql-python
```

Or you can download MySQL Python Connector from here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/

See also the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-python.html

---

Related:

["Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory" while installing mysql-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972259/mysql-python-install-problem-using-virtualenv-windows-pip)