# MySQLdb import causing error in Python 2.7.14

Tags: python, mysql-python

I have got the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Python27\databasepy.py",
>   line 1, in 
>       import MySQLdb   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb__init__.py", line 19, in
>   
>       import _mysql ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

While executing the following code:

```
import MySQLdb
from MySQLdb import Error
try:
    db = MySQLdb.Connect(host="localhost",port=3306,user="root",passwd="Azmat@123",db="test")
    cursor=db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT VERSION()")
    data=cursor.fetchone()
    print "Database version :%s " %data
    db.close()
except Error as er:
    print er
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't import MySQLdb module in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262379/cant-import-mysqldb-module-in-python)

Comment: I'll suggest you use `pymysql` to replace `MySQLdb`. The prior one is a pure-Python implementation.