# Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.6

I am using python 3.6. I am trying to install mysql for python.

I used pip install MySQL-python command but it gives me the error:

> Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory.

I did refer the question "[python - _mysql Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory when installing mysql-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33222815/python-mysql-cannot-open-include-file-config-win-h-no-such-file-or-direct)", it is saying to download mysql connector but the mysql connector is not compatible with python 3.6. So i still can't solve this problem.

I tried to download the mysql connector from "https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/ "