# Python pip install django mysql fails on Windows

Tags: python, mysql, django, windows

I am trying to setup a django project on Windows 10 using Python 3.5 and Django 1.9. When I run the pip command to install MySQL support I get the following error. MySQL 5.7 is installed and running.

```
PS H:\> pip install django mysql
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django in c:\python35\lib\site-packages
Collecting mysql
  Using cached mysql-0.0.1.tar.gz
Collecting MySQL-python (from mysql)
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
Installing collected packages: MySQL-python, mysql
  Running setup.py install for MySQL-python
    Complete output from command c:\python35\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\JKRATZ~1.EVE\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-kr3v2d0u\\MySQL-python\\setup.py';exec(compile(get
attr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\JKRATZ~1.EVE\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-id62narl-record\install-record.txt --single-version-ex
ternally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Co
nnector C 6.0.2\include" -Ic:\python35\include -Ic:\python35\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCL
UDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\shar
ed" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\winrt" /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
    _mysql.c
    _mysql.c(42): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python35\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\JKRATZ~1.EVE\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-kr3v2d0u\\MySQL-python\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', o
pen)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\JKRATZ~1.EVE\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-id62narl-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compi
le" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\JKRATZ~1.EVE\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-kr3v2d0u\MySQL-python
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972259/cannot-open-include-file-config-win-h-no-such-file-or-directory-while-inst

Answer (score 1):

Installing MySQL support of Django on Windows is suffering and I came across the same question just like you. For my situation, I use python3.4, django1.8.5, I solved this problem by download wheel file from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python) and use pip to install it:

> `pip install ***.whl`

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue with finding the include file "config-win.h".

Please check out this error message:

```
_mysql.c(42): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory
```

The have moved the include files to a separate folder.
Now they should be located in:

C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C 6.0.2\include

Please try the instructions from this link:
["Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory" while installing mysql-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972259/cannot-open-include-file-config-win-h-no-such-file-or-directory-while-inst)

Comment: There does not appear to be a config-win.h in the latest version of Connector C unless I'm missing something