# Inssues installing python-mysql on windows server 2012 r2

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to install mysql module on my woindows server 2012 r2. I am installing using pip. Initially I get the error:

```
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

So I installed VC++ compiler and that error was gone. Then when I tried again I got.

```
_mysql.c(34) : Fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory
```

So I installed mysql-connector-c-6.0.2-win32.msi from mysql website and tried again and this time I am getting new errors:

```
Collecting mysql
Collecting MySQL-python (from mysql)
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
Building wheels for collected packages: MySQL-python
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for MySQL-python ... error
  Complete output from command c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe -u -c "import
 setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1\\pip-build-yu816jlt\\MySQL-python\\setup.py
';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -
d C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\tmp5198acbgpip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.5
  copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5
  creating build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb
  creating build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
  running build_ext
  building '_mysql' extension
  creating build\temp.win32-3.5
  creating build\temp.win32-3.5\Release
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(
1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -Ic:\users\adminis
trator\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\include -Ic:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python35
-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10
\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
 Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.5\Rele
ase\_mysql.obj /Zl
  _mysql.c
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include\config-win.h(192): warning C4005: 'isnan': macro redefini
tion
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\math.h(264): note: see previous definition of 'isnan'

  C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include\config-win.h(203): warning C4005: 'SIZEOF_OFF_T': macro r
edefinition
  c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\include\pyconfig.h(346): note: see previous definitio
n of 'SIZEOF_OFF_T'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include\config-win.h(301): warning C4005: 'HAVE_STDDEF_H': macro
redefinition
  c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\include\pyconfig.h(675): note: see previous definitio
n of 'HAVE_STDDEF_H'
  _mysql.c(297): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
  _mysql.c(327): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
  _mysql.c(623): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
  _mysql.c(624): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
  _mysql.c(625): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
  _mysql.c(626): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
  _mysql.c(627): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
  _mysql.c(1118): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
  _mysql.c(1161): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
  _mysql.c(1165): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
  _mysql.c(1532): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED
,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\lib\opt" /LIBPATH:c:\users\administ
rator\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\pytho
n35-32\PCbuild\win32 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x
86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86" ker
nel32.lib advapi32.lib wsock32.lib mysqlclient.lib /EXPORT:PyInit__mysql build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\_mysql.obj /OUT:bu
ild\lib.win32-3.5\_mysql.cp35-win32.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\_mysql.cp35-win32.lib
     Creating library build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\_mysql.cp35-win32.lib and object build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\_mysql.
cp35-win32.exp
  mysqlclient.lib(typelib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func
  mysqlclient.lib(viosslfactories.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func
  mysqlclient.lib(my_winfile.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func
  mysqlclient.lib(my_messnc.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func
  mysqlclient.lib(client.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func
  mysqlclient.lib(my_thr_init.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func
  mysqlclient.lib(my_init.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func
  mysqlclient.lib(default.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func
  mysqlclient.lib(default.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _printf
  build\lib.win32-3.5\_mysql.cp35-win32.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120


  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for MySQL-python
  Running setup.py clean for MySQL-python
Failed to build MySQL-python
Installing collected packages: MySQL-python, mysql
  Running setup.py install for MySQL-python ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe -u -c "impo
rt setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1\\pip-build-yu816jlt\\MySQL-python\\setup.
py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --r
ecord C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-t8ide7pb-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed
--compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.5
    creating build\temp.win32-3.5\Release
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info
=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -Ic:\users\admin
istrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\include -Ic:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python
35-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\
10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windo
ws Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.5\Re
lease\_mysql.obj /Zl
    _mysql.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include\config-win.h(192): warning C4005: 'isnan': macro redefi
nition
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\math.h(264): note: see previous definition of 'isna
n'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include\config-win.h(203): warning C4005: 'SIZEOF_OFF_T': macro
 redefinition
    c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\include\pyconfig.h(346): note: see previous definit
ion of 'SIZEOF_OFF_T'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include\config-win.h(301): warning C4005: 'HAVE_STDDEF_H': macr
o redefinition
    c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\include\pyconfig.h(675): note: see previous definit
ion of 'HAVE_STDDEF_H'
    _mysql.c(297): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(327): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(623): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(624): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(625): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(626): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(627): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(1118): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(1161): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(1165): warning C4090: '=': different 'const' qualifiers
    _mysql.c(1532): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMB
ED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\lib\opt" /LIBPATH:c:\users\admini
strator\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\pyt
hon35-32\PCbuild\win32 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files
(x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86" k
ernel32.lib advapi32.lib wsock32.lib mysqlclient.lib /EXPORT:PyInit__mysql build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\_mysql.obj /OUT:
build\lib.win32-3.5\_mysql.cp35-win32.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\_mysql.cp35-win32.lib
       Creating library build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\_mysql.cp35-win32.lib and object build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\_mysq
l.cp35-win32.exp
    mysqlclient.lib(typelib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func
    mysqlclient.lib(viosslfactories.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func
    mysqlclient.lib(my_winfile.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func
    mysqlclient.lib(my_messnc.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func
    mysqlclient.lib(client.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func
    mysqlclient.lib(my_thr_init.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func
    mysqlclient.lib(my_init.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func
    mysqlclient.lib(default.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___iob_func
    mysqlclient.lib(default.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _printf
    build\lib.win32-3.5\_mysql.cp35-win32.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\link.exe' failed with exit status 11
20

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;
__file__='C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1\\pip-build-yu816jlt\\MySQL-python\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr
(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ADMINI~1\
AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-t8ide7pb-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with e
rror code 1 in C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-build-yu816jlt\MySQL-python\
```

Im out of ideas please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972259/cannot-open-include-file-config-win-h-no-such-file-or-directory-while-inst