# Error when install new python module

Tags: python, mysql, linux, windows

When i installed VC++ 14.0 and try "pip install mysql" in Windows Command Prompt then I get this error:

```
_mysql.c _mysql.c(42): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory
```

[image: Error]
Anyone knows how to fix it please ?

Comment: paste error log in the message as a text

Comment: _mysql.c
    _mysql.c(42): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------

Comment: Command "c:\users\duy\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Duy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-qyqgigxc\\MySQL-python\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Duy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-0eace40e-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Duy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-qyqgigxc\MySQL-python\

Comment: You [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40945642/edit) your question and paste error message there instead of image

Comment: May be this question will help you. Go through the answers of it.
[Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory” while installing mysql-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972259/cannot-open-include-file-config-win-h-no-such-file-or-directory-while-inst)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory" while installing mysql-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972259/cannot-open-include-file-config-win-h-no-such-file-or-directory-while-inst)