# Error while installing MySQL-python

Tags: python, mysql, pip

I'm using Python 2.7 and Django 1.9.4. I want to integrate my Django application with MySQL 5.7 database and I executed:

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

on Windows 7 machine 64-bit.

And getting Error :

```
    F:\Djangoproject\mysite>pip install MySQL-python
Collecting MySQL-python
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
Building wheels for collected packages: MySQL-python
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for MySQL-python ... error
  Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\chandra\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build
-3qbbxo\\MySQL-python\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__
, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d c:\users\chandra\appdata\local\temp\tmpoytuplpip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-2.7
  copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7
  creating build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
  creating build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  running build_ext
  building '_mysql' extension
  creating build\temp.win32-2.7
  creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release
  C:\Users\Chandra\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Dversion_info
=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -Ic:\python27\include -Ic:\python27\PC /Tc_mys
ql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
  _mysql.c
  _mysql.c(42) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Users\\Chandra\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit statu
s 2

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for MySQL-python
  Running setup.py clean for MySQL-python
Failed to build MySQL-python
Installing collected packages: MySQL-python
  Running setup.py install for MySQL-python ... error
    Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\chandra\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-bui
ld-3qbbxo\\MySQL-python\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file
__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\chandra\appdata\local\temp\pip-rskyc7-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release
    C:\Users\Chandra\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Dversion_in
fo=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -Ic:\python27\include -Ic:\python27\PC /Tc_m
ysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
    _mysql.c
    _mysql.c(42) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\Chandra\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit sta
tus 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\chandra\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-3qbbxo\\MySQL-python\
\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --
record c:\users\chandra\appdata\local\temp\pip-rskyc7-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code
1 in c:\users\chandra\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-3qbbxo\MySQL-python\
```

Comment: you are missing config-win.h file

Comment: Please edit your question with version(32/64bit OS,Mysql) included in it. Issue is  all about mysql connector

Comment: @ ShivkumarKondi: please don't make edits merely to add bold to technology names - they don't need them, since it does not make them more readable. A much more useful edit would be to fix case errors - they were all wrong here. Python, Django, Windows, MySQL, are much more readable if their proper case is observed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use precompiled python packages, which can be found here http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python

Answer (score 0):

You need a C compiler on your system. The easiest way is to use the on Microsoft provides.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=44266

Comment: My system already have Visual C++ Compiler although I repaired it with the new c++ compiler. Still Getting the same Error

Answer (score -1):

**About Python :**

First check is python running properly in command prompt.

If not Download and install python 2.7.

Once it is downloaded, you generally have to go to Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings > Advanced Tab > Environment Variables > Path > Edit.  Here you need to add the Windows path of your Python installation. As an example, mine is “C:\Python27”.  If you don’t add this to the Path variable, you won’t be able to run Python from the command line and it’ll be annoying to test things.

**Install pip :**

Next, we should install pip, the Python package manager (some of this section is from experience some from this stackoverflow page). In case you were wondering, Python 3.4 already has pip installed with it!  But if you don’t have it there are a few options.  If you have easy_install on your machine, you can simply navigate to the Python27\Scripts directory and type:

```
easy_install.exe pip
```

This should install pip for you.  If you don’t have easy_install, you can download a python script from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py).  Make sure to save that get-pip.py file as a .py file not .txt.  You can then run the script:

```
 python get-pip.py
```

Once pip is installed, you can add the directory where pip is to your path like we did before (probably something like “C:\Python27\Scripts”).

**About MySQL:**

```
pip install mysql-python
```

You may get the error Unable to find `vcvarsall.bat` either when installing pip or other packages (I got it from trying to install mysql-python package). This means Windows can’t find a C/C++ compiler (it’s looking for Visual Studio) which pip uses to install packages and install itself.

**Finally test it :**

You can check if mysql-python is correctly installed by going to the command prompt and typing:

```
C:\> python
>>>import MySQLdb
```

Comment: python is properly installed in my system also path is correctly set .

Comment: @Rahulchandra The Issue is all about mysql connector. look thiis answer. it may help you sure .http://stackoverflow.com/a/16619567/6107715

Answer (score -1):

Done with alot of research, even downloaded unofficial windows binaries for python extensions - again made disappointment.
Finally, after trying simply following command and it worked.

```
easy_install mysql-python
```

Answer (score -1):

Best way is to install `mysqlclient` in the case of getting errors in installing `mysql-python`. 
`mysqlclient` is a fork of it and hence it can be used as a substitute and it contains `MySQLdb` aswell. So, better go for it